# Importing ZipFoundation in Xcode using Carthage not working

Tags: ios, xcode, carthage, zipfoundation

I followed all the steps to import Zipfoundation in my project using Carthage but it doesn't work. I can import Alamofire without issues using Carthage so I am guessing the first steps are right.

Zipfoundation imports into the folder without issues. The main difference is that ZipFoundation mentions that the fetched project has to be integrated into your workspace by dragging ZIPFoundation.xcodeproj to Xcode's Project Navigator.

[image]

I dragged it in my project and nothing happened. So I drag the frameworks and added the information to the build phases like I did with Alamofire but still nothing.

when I type "Import Alamofire" Alamofire shows up but nothing for "Import ZIPFoundation"

Is there a step I am missing?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding dependencies as .xcodeproj can be a bit cumbersome because Xcode has the tendency to move the dragged-in file *under* an existing project.
But to add a dependency to a workspace, the dragged in project should be a *sibling* and not a *child* of the consuming project.

3 Things are important for that to work:

- Your project must be part of an Xcode Workspace (it can be a
  workspace that for now only contains one single project)
- ZIP Foundation has to be checked out via `carthage update --no-build`
- The project must be on the same level as the consuming project in the
  workspace:

[image]

You also don't need the "Copy Frameworks" script for ZIP Foundation when you integrate it with the method described above. The Carthage Build folder won't contain a binary framework when you use the `--no-build` option.
Just make sure that `ZIPFoundation.framework` is in the "Embedded Binaries" list of your target.

Comment: Thanks Thomas for the response but it still doesn't work. Created a workspace and followed the instructions but it still doesn't recognise "zipItem". I setup Zip using Carthage and that works fine but I would prefer to use zip foundation if possible. Any other ideas why it won't recognise it?

Comment: Hi, 
I just tested integrating the newest version of ZIP Foundation with Carthage and it works fine for me
What I did: 
1) Create Workspace "ZipTest"
2) Create Project "ZipTest" and add it to the workspace
3) Add Cartfile and add: github "weichsel/ZIPFoundation"
4) run: carthage update --no-build
5) Drag ./Carthage/Checkouts/ZIPFoundation/ZIPFoundation.xcodeproj into the workspace as shown in the above GIF
6) Add "ZIPFoundation.framework" to the "Embedded Binaries" list in the "General" tab of the "ZipTest" project
7) `import ZIPFoundation` in one of the source files
8) zipItem ...

Comment: It took a few seconds until Xcode picked up the embedded framework for code completion etc. It also briefly showed an "unknown module ZIPFoundation" error while I was typing, but triggering a build or waiting some time resolved that automatically.

Comment: Thank you Thomas! I did have to relaunch Xcode as it wouldn't recognise the framework at first but now its great!